# Push to array of objects at index

Tags: javascript, arrays

Basically I have two arrays of image files, one with thumbnails and one with originals, the index of the thumbnail is the same as the original in their respective array. I want a new array that contains the file path to each.

So basically `this.images` would look like this `[{path: x, originalPath: y}, {path: xx, originalPath: yy}, etc]`

```
importAll(r) {
    let thumnailArray = r.keys();
    thumnailArray = thumnailArray.filter(s => !s.includes('_og'));
    thumnailArray.forEach(key => (
        this.images.push({
            path: r(key),
        })
    ));

    let originalArray = r.keys();
    originalArray = originalArray.filter(s => s.includes('_og'));

// this doesnt work, just adds to the end of the array...
    originalArray.forEach(key => (
        this.images.push({
            pathOriginal: r(key),
        })
    ));
},
```

This doesn't work though:

```
originalArray.forEach((key, index) => (
    this.images[index].push({
        pathOriginal: r(key),
    })
));
```

How else can I accomplish this?

Comment: Please post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: `originalArray.forEach((key, index) => this.images[index].pathOriginal = r(key))` if you want to post process it. No need to push, you're changing objects, not adding more elements.

Comment: The question is not very clear to me, but aren't you looking for [.splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) ?

Comment: This worked, thanks. ```originalArray.forEach((key, index) => (this.images[index].pathOriginal = r(key)));``` Brains not working right today.